# Angular install doesn't recognize node

Tags: node.js, angular

I have been trying to install Angular but everytime this part:

> @angular/cli@12.0.3 postinstall C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli

> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

Seems to throw an error. I'm not sure if I need this to work or not so I'll leave the last couple lines of the log here.

```
1021 silly install @angular/cli@12.0.3
    1022 info lifecycle @angular/cli@12.0.3~install: @angular/cli@12.0.3
    1023 timing action:install Completed in 1ms
    1024 silly doSerial postinstall 10
    1025 silly postinstall @angular/cli@12.0.3
    1026 info lifecycle @angular/cli@12.0.3~postinstall: @angular/cli@12.0.3
    1027 verbose lifecycle @angular/cli@12.0.3~postinstall: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
    1028 verbose lifecycle @angular/cli@12.0.3~postinstall: PATH: C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.17.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Marco\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu\Scripts;C:\Program Files\ConEmu;C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu;C:\Python39\Scripts;C:\Python39;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27;C:\Program Files (x86)\Python27\Lib;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\PharosSystems\Core;C:\Program Files\PuTTY;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Alda";C:\Program Files (x86)\Lein;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Marco\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\Marco\Downloads\node-v14.17.0-win-x64;C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Roaming\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
    1029 verbose lifecycle @angular/cli@12.0.3~postinstall: CWD: C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli
    1030 silly lifecycle @angular/cli@12.0.3~postinstall: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node ./bin/postinstall/script.js' ]
    1031 silly lifecycle @angular/cli@12.0.3~postinstall: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
    1032 info lifecycle @angular/cli@12.0.3~postinstall: Failed to exec postinstall script
    1033 timing action:postinstall Completed in 108ms
    1034 verbose unlock done using C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-dd50e3766c58f868.lock for C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging
    1035 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 3767ms
    1036 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 15387ms
    1037 verbose stack Error: @angular/cli@12.0.3 postinstall: `node ./bin/postinstall/script.js`
    1037 verbose stack Exit status 1
    1037 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.17.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
    1037 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:376:20)
    1037 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.17.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
    1037 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:376:20)
    1037 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
    1037 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
    1038 verbose pkgid @angular/cli@12.0.3
    1039 verbose cwd C:\Users\Marco\Documents\Code\Web Dev\Angular
    1040 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
    1041 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "-g" "@angular/cli"
    1042 verbose node v14.17.0
    1043 verbose npm  v6.14.13
    1044 error code ELIFECYCLE
    1045 error errno 1
    1046 error @angular/cli@12.0.3 postinstall: `node ./bin/postinstall/script.js`
    1046 error Exit status 1
    1047 error Failed at the @angular/cli@12.0.3 postinstall script.
    1047 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    1048 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: have you tried deleting your node_modules folder, and re-installing? before you re-install, make sure packge-lock.json is not checked out.

Comment: I have tried reinstalling and installing with nvm windows. Looks like the actual reason is because I was trying to install angular using ConEmu instead of cmd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by going to the actual file location of script.js and running the node command with that path.
Like this:

> node AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/postinstall/script.js

Actually that only helped a little bit. The problem was I was trying to install Angular using ConEmu GitBash and I should've been using cmd.